# How to make autoscroll to an index when selected React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have just learnt React Native. And I have a problem when trying to
   create a Scrollable bar.

Ex:

[image]

And my expected is, when I selected Level 3, I want the scroll bar
   swipe like this.

Ex:

[image]

It means just 3 levels on screen and the last element will auto swipe when selected.

So, how can I do this? Any solution or keyword that I can search?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please use `scrollTo` function available in scrollview.

Please refer : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#scrollto

Comment: I'm using Flatlist and I've tried with `scrollToIndex()` func, but I dont know how to set the function for the last of 3 items on screen. It may have a formula to calculate the position and the last item will be set  `scrollToIndex()` to swipe when selected.

Comment: how about using scrollToPosition and giving x and y pos to them

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I'm trying to determine the position to set the function

Comment: Let me know if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use scrollTo function to scroll to exact position at which the screen is required. And sometimes ive faced scrollTo doesnt work in componentDidMount , there's a little trick , just use setTimeout and it will work . For eg .
`setTimeout(() =>_scrollView.scrollTo({y: this.state.scrollPosition}) ,1)`

Do try once and if its working.

Comment: My problem is, I dont know how to determine exactly the position of the last of 3 items on screen to set func for it. Do you know how to do it? Or formulate to determine the position every time select the last item

Comment: if you are using scroll view then inside `<ScrollView onScroll={this.handleScroll} >` and describe the func handleScroll as 
`handleScroll =(event) => {
    var currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    this.setState({scrollPosition:currentOffset})
  }`